# How to navigate to other layout from Grid in ViewCell of list using Xamarin Shared

Tags: listview, c#-4.0, grid, xamarin.forms

Here is my code:

```
public class BillDetailGridCell : ViewCell
    {
        public BillDetailGridCell()
        {

            Grid grid = new Grid
            {
                Padding = new Thickness(5, 5, 0, 0), 
                ColumnDefinitions =
            {
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) },
            },
            };

            Button BillIdLabel = new Button
            {
                //YAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                //XAlign = TextAlignment.Start
                BackgroundColor = Color.Green,
            };

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add item tapped to your listview?

```cs
var listview = new ListView();
listview.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(BillDetailGridCell));
listview.ItemTapped += (sender, e) =>
{
    // navigate to another page
};
```